# If Statement Post Formats: No post format selected

Tags: php

I'm working with post formats, most of my code looks similar to this:

```
if ( has_post_format( 'standard' )) {
  echo '<?php get_sidebar(); ?>';
}
if ( has_post_format( 'aside' )) {
  echo 'this is an aside';
}
if ( has_post_format( 'chat' )) {
  echo 'this is the video format';
}
```

But I also want one of the if statements to include how to call it if the user **did not** select a post format.  Anybody know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`get_post_format`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_format):

```
$format = get_post_format();
if ( false === $format )
    echo "no post format";
```

EDIT - an example using a switch statement:

```
$format = get_post_format();
switch( $format ){
    case "aside":
        echo "aside";
        break;
    case "chat":
        echo "chat";
        break;
    default:
        echo "standard";
}
```

Comment: Ooh... you were quicker on the draw! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Is there a way to integrate this into my current statement?

Comment: @Lucas - see my edit above.

Comment: I just realized this isn't working properly.  It pulls the excerpt up for all post formats even if it's only supposed to pull it up if there is no post format.

Comment: I'd have to see it in context. note that "standard" isn't a format. you'll see it in the UI when none is selected, but `get_post_format` will return false for "standard".

Comment: http://themeforward.com/demo2/ is where I'm running it.

Comment: For example, "Left Aligned Image" is a video post which uses the following code...
if ( has_post_format( 'video' )) {
   ?>
 <span class="sub-title"><?php the_time("F j, Y"); ?> &nbsp;/&nbsp; <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> &nbsp;/&nbsp; <?php the_category(', ') ?></span>
 <span class="index_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>
 <?php the_excerpt();
}

but a second excerpt is being called due to the no post format code of:
<?php
$format = get_post_format();
if ( false === $format )
?>
 <?php the_excerpt();
?>

Comment: because you break the if statement by closing php, outputting space, and then opening it again. try: `if( false === $format ){ the_excerpt(); }`

Answer (score 0):

If they don't assign a format, it gets standard I think, for css purposes?

```
<?php $format = get_post_format(); 
if ( false === $format ) 
    $format = 'standard'; 
    get_template_part( 'format', $format ); ?>
```

Is some of the if logic I use, checking for format to return false for conditionals