# A better code for no post format?

Tags: posts, php, post-formats

As suggested on this site, I am using this code to style an excerpt if no post format is selected/if it is a standard post.

```
<?php
$format = get_post_format();
if ( false === $format )
{
echo 'This is a default post';
the_excerpt();
}
?>
```

However, it seems there must be a better way to include it with one PHP statement... the rest of which follows this pattern:

```
if ( has_post_format( 'video' )) {
    ?>
    A VIDEO POST
    <?php the_content();
}
if ( has_post_format( 'audio' )) {
    ?>
    AN AUDIO POST
    <?php the_content();
}
```

Anybody know how to include the original code in this same if statement?  If, then...

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21628/if-statement-post-formats-no-post-format-selected/21630#21630

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand. Do you just want to join all the if-statements together? If that's the case you could use elseif, like so:

```
<?php
$format = get_post_format();
if ( false === $format ) {
echo 'This is a default post';
the_excerpt();
} elseif ( has_post_format( 'video' )) { ?>
   A VIDEO POST
    <?php the_content();
} elseif ( has_post_format( 'audio' )) { ?>
    AN AUDIO POST
    <?php the_content();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using template-part files, with `get_template_part()` and `get_post_format()`:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'post', get_post_format() ); ?>
```

This method will then look for, e.g. `post-gallery.php`, and fall back to `post.php` if either `post-gallery.php` doesn't exist, or if `get_post_format()` returns `false`.

Then, for each Post Format type, you simply create `post-{post-format-type}.php`, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use a switchcase instead.

```
switch ( get_post_format() ) {

case 'video':
  // video post code
  break;

case 'audio':
  // audio post code
  break;

default:
  // default post code
  break;

}
```